# Mockito MVC - how to pass value for @RequestParam binding a string array

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

I'd like to write a unit test using Mockito.

The method to be tested is written by **Spring MVC** as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html;charset=UTF-8")
@ResponseBody
public String save(String appName,
        @RequestParam(value = "platforms[]") String[] platforms,
        HttpServletRequest request) {}
```

I tried several ways to mock request value **platforms** which is **binding a string array** like '***string[]***'.

But, it seems it is still not working: the platforms value is null.

Here are the ways I tried:

**Way#1**

```
final String[] platforms = { "Android", "iOS" };
request.setAttribute("platforms", platforms);
request.setAttribute("platforms[]", platforms);
```

**Way#2**

```
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/application/save")
            .session(session).requestAttr("platforms[]", platforms)
            .requestAttr("platforms", platforms)
            .param("appName", "Just for test"));
```

Note: request is a mock object (**MockHttpServletRequest**)

Hope you can give me some idea to solve this problem. Thanks.

For more information, here are the print result when doing way#2:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
     HTTP Method = POST
     Request URI = /application/save
      Parameters = {appName=[Just for test]}
         Headers = {}

         Handler:
            Type = com.xxx.controller.ApplicationController
          Method = public java.lang.String com.xxx.controller.ApplicationController.save(java.lang.String,java.lang.String[],javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)

Resolved Exception:
            Type = org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException

    ModelAndView:
       View name = null
            View = null
           Model = null

        FlashMap:

 MockHttpServletResponse:
          Status = 400
   Error message = Required String[] parameter 'platforms[]' is not present
         Headers = {}
    Content type = null
            Body = 
   Forwarded URL = null
  Redirected URL = null
         Cookies = []
```

Comment: What is printed if you add .andDo(print()) after .perform on way 2 ? (print() is a method from MockMvcResultHandlers).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Thanks for the suggestion. Some of the information printed as follows : MockHttpServletResponse: Status = 400 Error message = Required String[] parameter 'platforms[]' is not present Headers = {} Content type = null Body = Forwarded URL = null Redirected URL = null Cookies = []

Comment: Try to pass your platforms as a .param instead of requestAttr. As per the doc, .param is used to set a request parameter while requestAttr to set a request *attribute*.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Thanks for the advice. I tried to set a request parameter like ; .param("platforms[]", "Andriod, iOS").param("platforms", "Andriod, iOS") It is working, Thanks